# save R list as individual element

Tags: r

Let's say I have a nested list in R. How can I `save` the list into `.Rdata` as individual top level elements of the list ?

What I mean is, e.g. sample data

```
samplist <- list(a=list(x=2, y=runif(10)),
                 b=list(x=3, y=rbinom(10, 5, .5)),
                 c=list(x=0, y=rnorm(10))
                )
```

The output I want is the equivalent of

```
a <- samplist$a
b <- samplist$b
c <- samplist$c
save(a, b, c, file=output.Rdata)
```

done automatically across a list with many top-level elements. I tried `unlist` with `recursive=F` but that flattened the lists in the nested list. How can I do it instead?

Comment: `list2env` will be a solution but you'll need to be careful with it in order not pollute your environment with lots of junk

Comment: You can use a for loop putting into a list the i-th samplist[[names(samplist)[i]]]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to store the environment:

```
do.call(save, 
        c(as.list(names(samplist)), 
          list(file = "output.Rdata", 
               envir = as.environment(samplist))))
load("output.Rdata")
print(a)
#$x
#[1] 2
#
#$y
#[1] 0.6815263 0.5448165 0.3346296 0.2127811 0.1804896 0.8416717 0.1060889 0.5679649 0.6392396 0.9770226
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution by converting list as an environment.

```
# Test list
samplist <- list(a=list(x=2, y=runif(10)),
                 b=list(x=3, y=rbinom(10, 5, .5)),
                 c=list(x=0, y=rnorm(10)))

# Convert list as an environment
env <- as.environment(samplist)

# Save objects form the environment
save(list = ls(env), file = "output.Rdata", envir = env)

# Load file
load("output.Rdata")
```